# ¿Cómo puedo usar el valor del iterador en cada iteración en un bucle for?

Tags: python, variables

Si bien estoy programando con PySide2, no he etiquetado dicho módulo porque creo que es algo de Python y no abarca otros módulos...

Entiendo un poco el sistema de variables de Python como por ejemplo, al igualar un mismo valor con varias variables, en realidad se ocupa un único espacio en memoria y todas las variables apuntan a ese valor, en vez de replicarse el mismo como se haría por ej en C++.

Pero tengo un problema al reutilizar la variable, por ejemplo el iterador de un bucle FOR. Deseo mediante un bucle asignar a una serie de botones que se crean dinámicamente, el evento clicked a una función con un parámetro, ej:

```
for i in range(10):
    btn = QPushButton(self)
    btn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.Funcion(i))
```

Obviamente el código es más largo y complejo, pero la idea es la misma, y es que sin importar el botón que se presione, siempre se llama a la self.Funcion con el valor de 9, es decir, que a pesar de que a cada botón se le ha asignado un valor distinto, al final a todos le indica el mismo, que es con el cuál ha terminado el bucle, el último valor de la variable i.

Antes me habían eliminado una pregunta que estaría duplicada y me llevaba como solución usar el módulo de copy pero sin importar si uso copy.copy() o copy.deepcopy(), el resultado sigue siendo el mismo, y tampoco funciona un:

```
for contador, valor in enumerate(range(10), start=0):
    btn = QPushButton(self)
    btn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.Funcion(i))
```

Comment: Siento no tener tiempo ahora para darte una respuesta. Cambia la función lambda por `lambda x=i: self.Function(x)`

Comment: Si bien desconozco si esa línea de código soluciona ese problema, en sí el bucle es más complejo y utilizo dicho valor en varias oportunidades donde siempre sucede lo mismo, por eso quería ver si existe la posibilidad de utilizar dicho valor como a mí me gustaría.

Answer (score 1):

Por si a alguien le pasa algo similar que de hecho calculo que debe ser un problema normal, yo por el momento lo soluciono llamando a otra función dentro del bucle. El efecto es como ser en C++ un pasaje por valor.

```
def funcion1():
    for i in range(10):
        btn = QPushButton(self)
        funcion2(btn, valor)

def funcion2(objeto, valor):
    objeto.clicked.connect(lambda: self.Funcion3(valor))
```

De esta manera puedo asignar como en el ejemplo a los 10 botones el llamado a una Funcion3 con un valor específico, para el ejemplo.

En realidad en mi programa es muy útil porque además hago muchas cosas más como indicarle un texto, un formato, etc, y son todos distintos dependiendo de algunas condiciones y de su valor. De lo contrario, si sigo configurando todo dentro del bucle, todos los botones me quedarían configurados de igual forma que el último botón.